# How can i deploy my web application in apache using jenkins?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, centos, jenkins-cli

I have to deploy my web application (which is made in React) in Apache2 using Jenkins.

I want jenkins instead of redirecting the repository data to "Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/" to automatically redirect them to "/var/www/" and build the build there when a push is made and so on updating the website automatically.

I've been looking for many parts and I can't find information that can help me, I don't know if it's possible.

I use Ubuntu as operating system, but later I will deploy the Jenkins server to CentOS Stream.

So information for either one can work for me.

Try using bash command but it didn't work

"dir("folder") {
sh "pwd"
}"

In folder I added the path to "/www/var/home/osboxes/jenkins/var/jenkins_home/workspace/CI - CD" but it gave me the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foqDT.png)

Comment: How do you deploy your application manually? Do the same.

Comment: I deploy the file via FTP to the apache server, but now I want to automate it with jenkins.

Comment: What is the shell command to make it redirect to the apache folder and not the jenkins workspace folder?

Comment: Or how could I do it?

Comment: `the file via FTP to the apache server` So do the same from. There is a shell command `lftp`. `What is the shell command to make it redirect to the apache folder and not the jenkins workspace folder?` What is "it" you want to redirect? I do not understand, do not redirect, do exactly the same you do locally. Locally you deploy the file via ftp, do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oders of complexity:

1. You can use jenkins [publish over ssh plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/) to copy your folder from the workspace to the remote server. You must generate a key your jenkins server and copy it on the deployment target. ( don't use user/pass as it is very insecure) .
2. you can make a small ansible role that jenkins can use to: connect to the server , backup the existing folder with a timestamp, delete old backups , copy the new content from workspace and restart the server.
3. [dockerize your app](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-dockerise-a-react-app/), push your image and make jenkins run a remote command on the remote server to update the running container. If you use tags , the rollbacks will be easy . This way downtime is very low (seconds)

For all these try to use jenkins pipelines as code and commit your jenkinsfile in the project code.

Answer (score 0):

> I deploy the file via FTP to the apache server, but now I want to automate it with jenkins.

Great, so deploy the file via FTP to the apache server with Jenkins. There is a command `lftp`. I typically use docker image with commands that I need, like https://hub.docker.com/r/minidocks/lftp .

```
docker.image('minidocks/lftp').inside() {
    # h
    sh 'lftp -u login,password yourapacheserver.host.com -e "put  ./yourfile ; exit "'
}
```

I would put that `lftp` command line in a script so you can test it locally first.